# Save simple WMS as WFS layer

Tags: polygon, wms, wfs, linestring

I wonder if there is an easy way to transfer my WMS files to shapefiles/WFS.

With satellite images I understand it isn't so easy to do this in an accurate way, but perhaps with my layers it is. What I've done now is simply creating new layers and drawing polygons and lines myself, but it isn't very precise. I should probably do something with image classification to do it in a more precise way. However the tool: "Semi automatic Image classification" seems rather complicated to me, and I'm not sure if it works without satellite images. So what would be the easiest, but a precise way as well to change these files into WFS/shapefiles?

URL layer 1:
https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/keringenimwa/wms/v1_0
Source layer 1: crs=EPSG:28992&layers=waterkering&styles=Waterkering&format=image/png&url=https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/keringenimwa/wms/v1_0

URL layer 2: https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/keringenimwa/wms/v1_0
Source layer 2:
crs=EPSG:28992&layers=beschermingszone&styles=Beschermingszone&format=image/png&url=https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/keringenimwa/wms/v1_0

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may be able to get at the underlying vector data, for this WMS using a GetFeatureInfo request, and using GeoJSON as the INFO format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using QGIS you can save the WMS layer as Raster file(geo tiff) and then later convert the raster to vector (shape file) using QGIS plugins

1. Load the wms into QGIS - check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3UTqQ6lw-M
2. Save WMS to raster tiff - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exs4D5lgMwo
3. Then convert raster to vector - https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html
   you tube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOfiVPadjMw

Comment: Great! That worked. The only issue that I have now is that the Line layer 1, has been turned into a polygon. I then used polygon to lines, but it returns the outside lines of the polygons and not the original line which lies in the center. I tried the HCMGIS plugin but it gives me a skeleton, so still have some figuring out to do.